# Using a view bounds with scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm taking my first foray into scalaz by converting an existing class to use the *Monoid* trait. What I am trying to achieve is to set a view bound on my class type parameter to ensure that it can only be used with types that can be implicitly converted to a Monoid. My (simplified) class definition is thus:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Foo[T <% Monoid[T]](v: T)

new Foo(42)
```

Compiling this simple example gives the compiler error:

```
error: No implicit view available from Int => scalaz.Monoid[Int].
```

Previously this view bound was defined against my own custom trait with an implicit conversion from T to the trait and this worked fine.

What am I missing now that I have converted this to scalaz?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are supposed to be using a context bound, and not a view bound there.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Foo[T : Monoid](v: T)

new Foo(42)
```

The `T : Monoid` notation means that there is an implicit of type `Monoid[T]` in scope. In fact, it desugars to the following:

```
case class Foo[T](v: T)(implicit ev: Monoid[T])
```

This is known as type class pattern and you can read more about it [here](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help. Knew it was something obvious. Thanks for the link - some good reading for later.